# Is there an R function that performs LASSO regression on multiple imputed datasets and pools results together?

Tags: r, regression, imputation, r-mice, lasso-regression

I have a dataset with 283 observation of 60 variables. My outcome variable is dichotomous (Diagnosis) and can be either of two diseases. I am comparing two types of diseases that often show much overlap and i am trying to find the features that can help differentiate these diseases from each other. I understand that LASSO logistic regression is the best solution for this problem, however it can not be run on a incomplete dataset.

So i imputed my missing data with MICE package in R and found that approximately 40 imputations is good for the amount of missing data that i have.

Now i want to perform lasso logistic regression on all my 40 imputed datasets and somehow i am stuck at the part where i need to pool the results of all these 40 datasets.

The `with()` function from MICE does not work on .glmnet

```
# Impute database with missing values using MICE package:

imp<-mice(WMT1, m = 40)

#Fit regular logistic regression on imputed data

imp.fit <- glm.mids(Diagnosis~., data=imp, 
                    family = binomial)
# Pool the results of all the 40 imputed datasets:

summary(pool(imp.fit),2)
```

The above seems to work fine with logistic regression using glm(), but when i try the exact above to perform Lasso regression i get:

```
# First perform cross validation to find optimal lambda value:

CV <- cv.glmnet(Diagnosis~., data = imp,
                     family = "binomial", alpha = 1, nlambda = 100)
```

When i try to perform cross validation I get this error message:

```
 Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
    cannot coerce class ‘"mids"’ to a data.frame
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: I seem to remember that `mice` requires that the method returns a covariance matrix (check the docs to confirm); lasso does not have this. I suppose you could loop through the imputed datasets manually, run the lasso, and then think of some way to  combine predictions etc.

Comment: @user20650, thank you for your reply. By looping through them you mean i should extract all the imputed datasets (in my case 40) with function complete() and than perform lasso on each one of the completed 40 datasets? And when i do this how can i combine the predictions? i can't just average the output?

Comment: I don't know but Ive read of various ways of combining predictions but ive never done (or thought on) this. ps a quick search lead to http://mami.r-forge.r-project.org/ which may offer some alt (at a glance the manual has a section on lasso).

Comment: @user20650 I have came across that mami package and to be honest (i am very new to R) i did not understand the output: 
Mami<-mami(imp,method="LASSO",missing.data = "imputed", outcome="Diagnosis",model = "binomial",
     kfold = 5)  ---->which showed me a list of  ' estimates' and not the output i expected from LASSO. can you help me with this, i am so stuck right now.. :(

Comment: Can nobody help with this??

Comment: Karima; it may be worth asking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as this is now really more of a stats problem than a programming one

Comment: the formula doesn't work for cv.glmnet and unfortunately, there is no function to pool your estimates together. mice only provides one for glm or lm

Answer (score 0):

A thought:
Consider running the analyses on each of the 40 datasets. 
Then, storing which variables are selected in each in a matrix. 
Then, setting some threshold (e.g., selected in >50% of datasets).